# Adobe Phonegap build: "Error: upload failed; please try again [50]" and "index.html not present"

Tags: jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

When I try to upload my project as a zip to Adobe Phonegap Build, I can count on getting these three outcomes randomly:

- no error message
- index.html not present
- Error: upload failed; please try again [50]

Usually, once the error [50] message comes up, my only recourse is to delete the project and start over, making the process of code iteration more cumbersome and rendering hydration irrelevant. It even happens when i strip my code down to the most basic jQuery Mobile page.

I recognize that something in my code could be the problem and I'm not looking for a review and diagnosis, I just want to know if ANYONE knows what error [50] means, or has a general idea why either error keeps happening, so I can try to figure out where to go from here. Thanks to anyone who can provide some insight.

Comment: Give use your folder structure.

Comment: Thanks for responding. In the root directory there's index.html and config.xml

Subdirectories are css, images, js, res and themes (I created a custom jQm theme).

I'm using WinZip 19.0 at default settings to zip the file set.

I've tried adding and removing directories (and updating my script calls in my index.html file) and continue to get the same result.

Comment: Check your html file very carefully then - make sure it conforms to what need specifically on Phonegap Build. Your folder structure sounds fine. I use Github btw - you can can just pull from the PGB site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error and a considerable amount of angst I stumbled onto a solution, and I'm posting it in case someone else comes across this problem.

Turns out files compressed with either 7-Zip or WinZip will cause this error. Compression utilities that worked for me are:

- The "compress" function from within Finder in OSX
- The "download" function when accessing the files from Google Drive in a Chrome browser.

Both methods are available from the right-click menu when the files to be compressed are highlighted.

Comment: It may have worked for you but it has nothing to do with the compression mechanism in my case -- I've uploaded ZIP files compressed with Windows, and Powershell (`Compress-Archive`) to Phonegap, with success, but at some point files compressed through exactly the same procedure just breaks with the error you mentioned. The only solution I have come up with is to remove the app record and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to streamline your upload to phonegap build process, I would recommend using the phonegap remote build API. This will save you a countless amount of time over manually zipping and uploading each time you make a change to your code. You'll probably not see your error messages anymore :)

Simply run on a terminal/command prompt at the root of your local development phonegap/cordova project (you will be asked to login initially):

`phonegap remote build <platform>`

For all phonegap remote API methods run at the terminal:

`phonegap remote -help`

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for the response. I'm not sure I'm following you, are you referring to Adobe's "Phonegap Build" or Cordova/Phonegap? I'm using the Adobe service, where afaik there's no terminal / command line access.  Am I missing something?

Comment: The above refers to using Adobe's PhoneGap Build service. Running the commands above sends your local phonegap/cordova project to the remote/cloud Adobe PhoneGap build service.

To confirm, you should run the command locally - i.e. at the location where you develop your source code.